# At which scale searching the cost of transforming a list to set will be compensated compare to judge item in a list?

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

The prime slice of code is like, in which the small_list is changing daynamically:

```
for i in big_set:          # big_set is a huge set
    if i in small_list:    # small_list is a tiny list
        print i
```

And I know searching item in a list is slow, so I want change this code into:

```
for i in big_set:         
    if i in set(small_list):    # convert list to set
        print i
```

But here comes my concern, as small_list is small, and certainly call the set()
function will costs time. So, at which scale(how many items are there in the list), the time costs of calling set() function will be compensated by its efficiency?

It could be a vague range. But I need to know an estimation.
 It's a trivial matter, but it really bothers me.

Comment: While the interpeter will probably optimize it anyway, a better practice is usually to create the set out of the main loop, and guarantee the set is built only once, and not in each iteration.

Comment: Regarding which will be faster to what sizes: Benchmark, and use hypothesis testing to check out, the answer relies on the python version you are using, the architecture of the machine, and more and more.

Comment: @amit, I totally agree with you. And I did that in my code. But here the problem is, the small_list is changing dynamically.

Comment: @Zen you should probably have mentioned that. But a set isn't immutable, why not create the set then change that instead of the list?

Comment: @Zen if the small_list is changing dynamically, and you cannot maintain the set for each change - there is no point in creating the set, it will need to iterate the list itself.

Comment: Also, an even better practice: Iterate the small list, and print elements that are in `big_set`. This will require `O(|smallList|)` time, rather than `O(|smallList|*|bigSet|)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe, that's a good idea.

Comment: @amit, brilliant idea, that hit me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's answer your question:

1. Note that there is no point in building a set only to search in it once. Building the set from the list is slower than iterating it once.
2. In general case, "which is faster" (in real life, not theoretic complexity) should usually be determined by using a benchmark and [hypothesis tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing)

After that is established, let's make some suggestions how to do even better than the suggestions mentioned:

1. You can build the `set` BEFORE starting the main loop, and make sure it is maintained correctly, and elements are added/deleted whenever they are added/deleted from `small_list`. [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) can help you achieve it.
2. Even better practice will be to iterate the `small_list`, for each element in the small list, check if it is in the set, and print it. Since you are actually calculating [*set intersection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) - the results will be the same, but the later is more efficient.